# What is causing exceeding of Rate Limit in My Program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, stackexchange-api

I am using the Stackoverflow API to collect the tags in Stackoverflow. I am using NodeJS and am facing a typical problem. My rate limit gets exceeded after 230-250 requests.AS far as I have read it allows <30req/sec . So it should work fine according to my program, but instead I get an exception after 200+ cycles.MY nodejs code is as follows:-

```
var request=require('superagent');
var request=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://shivkumarganesh:11111@paulo.mongohq.com:10090/lklklklkkkkl_gshiv_sk');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Connected');
});

//Schema for Tags
var tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    count:Number,
    is_required:Boolean
,    is_moderator_only:Boolean,
    has_synonyms:Boolean});

var Tags = mongoose.model('Tags', tagSchema);

var saveSchema = function(Model){
    Model.save();
}
 ///usr/local/lib/node_modules/superagent  
var i=1;
var req=function(){
    request.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/tags?page='+i+'&pagesize=100&fromdate=1199145600&todate=1377648000&order=asc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow')
   .set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
   .set('Accept', 'application/json')
   .end(function(res){
     if (res.ok && i<346) {
       console.log('yay got ' + res.body);
       var jsonResponse = res.body;
       console.log(jsonResponse.items.length);
       for(var j=0;j<jsonResponse.items.length;j++)
       {
           var model = new Tags(jsonResponse.items[j]);
           saveSchema(model);
       }
       i++;
       console.log("Number of Iteration ---- > "+i);
       setTimeout(function() {
           req();
       }, 3000);

     } else {
       console.log('Oh no! error ' + res.text);
       console.log('Processing Over'+i)
     }
   });

}
req();
```

Please help me to figure this out.If possible please rectify the program.
Note: I amusing MongoHQ to store data.

Comment: API-Key is just a sample ket, even without it , it works fine.

Comment: Before rating negative could you pls look in where the program is going wrong. I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this informative link: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Specifically:

> A dynamic throttle is also in place on a per-method level. If an application receives a response with the backoff field set, it must wait that many seconds before hitting the same method again.

So check out the `backoff` field returned, and wait for that much before doing another request.

Comment: Thanks..for the reply. It matches my question.